# c++ Using subclasses

Tags: c++, subclass

I have this variable; Furniture **furnitures;
Which is an abstract baseclass to 2 subclasses, Bookcase and Couch. I add these randomly;

```
furnitures[n++] = new Bookcase ();
furnitures[n++] = new Couch();
.
.
```

For the sake of explaination. Lets set some minor variables.
Furniture private: name, prize
Bookcase private: size
Couch private: seats

How would I go about if I wanted to print out information such as; name and seats?

There are various of problems in this issue. 1, distinguish which subclass is which when I use Furniture[i]. 2, I dont want to blend too much unneccessary functions between the two subclasses that arent needed.

Comment: I hope `furnitures` is initialized so indexing it is well-defined. In any case, you'd do better having a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Furniture>>`.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Furniture 
{
    virtual void output() = 0;
};

class Couch : public Furniture
{
    void output() override;
};

class Bookshelf : public Furniture
{
    void output() override;
};
```

You could define the function in Furniture to save from duplicate code in subclasses like this:

```
void Furniture::output()
{
    // We assume here the output is to cout, but you could also pass the necessary
    // stream in as argument to output() for example.
    cout << name << price;
}

void Couch::output()
{
    Furniture::output();
    cout << seats;
}

void Bookshelf::output()
{
    Furniture::output();
    cout << size;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should **never use arrays polymorhphically**. Read the first item (I think it's the first) in Scott Meyers' *More Effective C++* book to find out why!

In fact, you should almost never use raw arrays in C++ anyway. A correct solution is to use a `std::vector<Furniture*>`.

> How would I go about if I wanted to print out information such as;
>   name and seats?
>
> There are various of problems in this issue. 1, distinguish which
>   subclass is which when I use Furniture[i]. 2, I dont want to blend too
>   much unneccessary functions between the two subclasses that arent
>   needed..

You are facing this problem because you are abusing object-oriented programming. It's simple: object-oriented programming makes sense when different types implement an **abstract common operation** and the concrete type is chosen at run-time. In your case, there is no common operation. Printing (or receiving) the number seats is for one type, printing (or receiving) a size is for the other type.

That's not to say that it's bad or wrong, but it's simply not object-oriented.

Now C++ would not be C++ if it didn't offer you a dangerous tool to get out of every dead end you've coded yourself into. In this case, you can use Run-Time Type Identifcation (RTTI) to find out the concrete type of an object. Google for `typeid` and `dynamic_cast` and you'll quickly find the solution. But remember, using RTTI for this problem is a *workaround*. Review your class design, and change it if necessary.

Comment: Can you summarize why to never use an array of pointers to polymorphic objects, for those who don't have the book?

Comment: I've just read the item you refer to, Item 3 - *'Never treat arrays polymorphically'*, and it doesn't apply to the OP's code. The item refers to problems which can occur if you try to do something like this: `void foo(Base array[]){// Do something with array elements}; foo(Derived array[10];` - in this case, `foo` will not behave properly as the compiler will be expecting it to deal with Base sized elements, but you have passed in Derived size objects (which are likely bigger). The OP is storing base/derived class pointers in an array (as opposed to objects), so he will not face this problem.

Comment: Thinking about it... Yes, you are correct. I guess I got a wrong impression from the OP's question. So, the advice is correct, but it apparently does not apply to the question at hand. Thank you!